# Check if value in a column exists in URL using lamda function

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns. One is the URL and other is the username.

```
+----------------------------------------+---------------+
|                  URL                   |   Username    |
+----------------------------------------+---------------+
| johnsmith/stackoverflow.com/?=abc      | johnsmith     |
| michealrod/stackoverflow.com/?=payment | michealrod    |
| stephaniejean/stackoverflow.com/?=abc  | stephaniejean |
+----------------------------------------+---------------+
```

I want to write a lambda function that that checks if the username exists i the URL. I am trying to write something like this but getting an error

```
df['exists'] = df.apply(lambda x : df['Username'] in df['URL']).any()
```

So basically I am trying to get a TRUE if the username is a part of URL and False if the username does not exists in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is clean, a list comprehension is relatively efficient:

```
df['exists'] = [x in y for x, y in zip(df['Username'], df['URL'])]
```

You can use `apply` but with worse performance:

```
df['exists'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Username'] in row['URL'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with `numpy` `core.defchararray.find`

```
df['exists']=np.core.defchararray.find(df.URL.values.astype(str),df.Username.values)!=-1
```